# webspider for site with shadow-root tag

Tags: web-crawler, tornado, etl, shadow-dom

```
How to adapt this web spider 
to search the pages
 on sites that contain shadow-root tag ?
```

sites:

http://www.cpasparks.com/

http://www.highrockaccounting.com/

http://www.steelecpas.com/

http://www.superiorlinenlv.com/

tornado webspider:
https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/webspider/webspider.py
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tornadoweb/tornado/stable/demos/webspider/webspider.py

It works good with almost all the sites except them.

Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If Shadow DOMs are in the *open* mode their DOM trees can be inspected via the shadowRoot property:

```
console.log( anElement.shadowRoot )  //display the shadow DOM
```

You can also access the insterted nodes by using [`getInsertedNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes) on the `<slot>` elements.